# How to install rear rack & fenders on a vintage road bike

Tags: road-bike, touring, rack, vintage, fenders

How feasible is it to install a rear rack and fenders on common vintage road bike frames (e.g. Peugeot PX-8, Raleigh Record/Super Course etc.), and how can it be done, exactly?-- on my "true" randonneur from Motobecane (which is now sadly dead), the frame had eyelets to allow a rack to be installed:
[image: 1971 Motobecane rear rack eyelets]

However, on some other bikes, the rear rack is merely "clamped" onto the frame:
[image: 1983 Raleigh Royal rear rack clamp]

Considering that e.g. a Raleigh Super Course doesn't have eyelets for a rear rack, would it then be possible to install a rack via this latter "clamp" method? Would it be able to hold a proper amount of weight, e.g. 20kg? Likewise, how would one put fenders on such a bike (if this is indeed possible)?

Comment: Of course it is possible. The question is, whether the frame is strong enough for it and is it OK to break it if it is not. I personally wouldn't do it and if I did, I'd keep the load at few kilograms. Old (early 80s and older) road bikes generally have enough space for full length fenders and clamps are fine for them.

Comment: @ojs that's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Have you looked into seat post racks? While they may be commonly sold for mtb use, I've used one for commuting on a (modern) road bike without mounting points. The one I had was only rated to something like 12 or 15 kg but it wasn't chosen with load capacity in mind.

Comment: @ChrisH: I did look into seat post racks (and even had one on a cheap hybrid bike many moons ago), but I really didn't feel comfortable buying something for a significant amount of cash which I can't "trust": On an irregular basis, I carry stuff like huge amount of fruits and vegetables, which are likely brushing up against that 12-15 kg limit...

Comment: @errantlinguist on smooth road I'd feel comfortable exceeding that limit by quite a bit, at least for short journeys (i.e. not touring). As they're aimed at mtbs, the limit is set based on rather harsh riding conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this frame have mounting points down on the rear dropouts?  The sort  sometimes used for mudguards/fenders, which can be repurposed for the downshafts of a rack.  Since they hold most of the weight, a front mount is relatively lightly loaded.

I made a couple of clamps out of thin sheet metal for my rack, which wrap around the seat stays and bolt through the rack.

View from above
 [image: Top view]

Looking backwards
[image: Front view]

Each bracket is a short strip of aluminium which is wrapped around the seat stay and then back on itself.  The bolt is a stainless steel one, and is (edit: should be!) double-nutted for vibration resistance.

Remember at least 2/3 of the weight is taken by the rear struts.  I've had a good 12-15 kilograms on this rack.   The black plastic is a substitute for a mudguard/fender, which does fine protecting my backside and bag, but does little to keep the bike and chain clean.

Comment: You can also buy similar brackets ready made. Search for  "Tubus Clamp Set For Seat Stay Mounting" or "P-clip".

Comment: @armb Good finding.  I had the scrap metal, and my time was cheaper than money for a while.

Comment: @armb: Thanks for the heads-up regarding P-clips-- I'm looking into them as they seem to be the only (commercial) solution available...

Answer (score 1):

After a very lengthy period of research, I came across what seems to be the only two proper purpose-built luggage racks for road bikes without eyelets which are not light-duty "seatpost racks" (at least on the part of the Web which is in the languages I understand):

## [Streamliner Road DLX](http://www.axiomgear.com/products/racks/streamliner/streamliner-road-dlx/) from [Axiom Cycling Gear](http://www.axiomgear.com)

[image: Axiom Streamliner Road DLX luggage rack]

### Pros

- Looks very sturdy: It's even made of titanium and is rated to 50kg!
- Has a mount for a rear light/reflector.
- Works without any eyelets at all: It's mounted onto to the frame using the brake caliper bolt and the rear wheel's [quick-release skewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_release_skewer).

### Cons

- It only comes in black and the bike I'm mounting it to is plum-colored with chrome accessories: It would look like a tumour growing on the bike's back.

## [Roadie Rack](http://topeak.com/products/Racks/roadie_rack_sl) from [Topeak](http://topeak.com/)

[image]

### Pros

- It's available in a silver aluminium finish, which would blend in with the chrome on my bike better than black would.
- Adjustable struts so that even without seeing it in-person at a shop, I'd feel safe ordering it in regards to its compatibility with my frame.

### Cons

- It's basically a glorified seatpost rack: The struts attach to the seat stays via "adhesive straps".
- In accordance with being a glorified seatpost rack, it's ridiculously flimsy: It's rated for only 7kg!-- even some seatpost racks can hold more than that!
- Despite being available in a silver finish, it's so ugly that I'd rather put the black Streamliner Road DLX on my bike.

## Conclusion

- There are indeed a few luggage rack options designed for road bike frames on the market, but they are so few that they are all a compromise.
- It is possible for a luggage rack with struts to actually be worse than a seatpost rack when it comes to carrying capacity.
- If you're going to have a bike and look for obscure products for it, it's best to have a bike which is black or at least has black accents.

Comment: There is nothing about colour that can't be fixed by a paint can and some time.